# Remove () from string before LOCAL INFILE import

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, csv

I have various strings formatted as below

> 123 Pretend Address, ABC 123 (First Let)

I need to remove the information in the brackets at the end of the string before importing with MySQL, how do I do that?

```
Query = """ LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "letagree.csv" REPLACE INTO TABLE let_agree 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES """

cursor.execute(Query)
jupixupdate.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So you want to remove (First Let) from string or just ( and )?

Comment: (First Let)  @Maxqueue

Answer (score 0):

Need to use regular expressions

For following string

```
test = "123 Pretend Address, ABC 123 (First Let)"
```

Now to remove the (First Let) from string

```
import re
print(re.sub(r" ?\([^)]+\)", "", test))
```

So following should work for your example:

```
cursor.execute(re.sub(r" ?\([^)]+\)", "", query))
```